# Uninstalled npm packages but they are still installed

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, yo

I want to start a fresh installation of the yoemen but it seems that I can't get rid of it in the first place

when I run `npm remove -g yo bower grunt-cli` it removes normally but when I type `yo` I get the normal generator menu:

[image]

How do I get rid of all the generators (the ones shown in the picture) and remove yoemen to reinstall it?

thank you

**edit**

```
username@username-Inspiron-3521:~/Documents/angular/testing2$ npm remove -g yo
npm WARN uninstall not installed in /home/username/npm/lib/node_modules: "yo"
username@username-Inspiron-3521:~/Documents/angular/testing2$ yo
? 'Allo username! What would you like to do? (Use arrow keys)
  Run a generator
❯ Angular 
  Express Angular 
  Angular Fullstack 
  Karma
```

Comment: And what's happen if you try `npm remove yo` ?

Comment: @TGrif I've edited the question with what happen when I do what you asked

Comment: And what do `type yo` and `realpath $(type -p yo)` say?

Comment: I mean maybe it's not installed globally, try without `-g`

Comment: seems like my paths where a bit odd, I fixed them following this tutorial http://www.competa.com/blog/2014/12/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove everything and start over again.

To install latest node and npm:
https://gist.github.com/jsantana90/46c9bb977d5775df1516

and to fix the path I followed this tutorial:
http://www.competa.com/blog/2014/12/how-to-run-npm-without-sudo/